# Review (LQ): whats up with "New Contributor"?

Tags: support

While reviewing the LQ queue I was presented with something new:
[image]

What is the purpose of the "New contributor" accompanied by a waving hand?

<del>Why is it shown with someone who has already 99 points?</del> Found that one myself :-)

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314287/come-take-a-look-at-our-new-contributor-indicator people should look at the "featured on meta" sidebar

Answer (score 7):

It's just a user that's new to this site, so give them some slack as they don't know what we all take for granted.

Definition of "New":

- Hasn't asked many questions / given many answers here here but might be another [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) somewhere else if their score hovers around 100.
- Is totally new to the entire Stack Exchange network if score is in the single digits (Haven't seen any others for the moment) and:

  - doesn't know a comment from an answer,
  - thinks this is a discussion forum,
  - has no clue what code formatting is
  - asks Kali h@çk3rz questions (or at least thinks they do),
  - so ***be even more patient*** <sub><sup>(or just avoid them if you're having a bad hair day)</sup></sub>.

Comment: I liked the "bad hair day" comment. :-)

Comment: Another English expression added to your vocabulary @CristianaNicolae (No, not a native English speaker myself neither)